# IE6 jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

Can anyone see anything specific that would be causing issues with jQuery in ie6? No jQuery elements are loading at all in ie6. ALL OTHER BROWSERS ARE FINE!!!! Thank you so much for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>{tag_pagetitle}</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/tabs.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link href="/stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/gallery-1.0.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/facebox/facebox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/ie.css" bc="1" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/ie6site.css" bc="1" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="gallerydetail">
<div id="site"><img src="http://thecreativealliance.org/images/top-corners_03.gif" width="900" height="3" alt="" />
  <div id="banner"><img alt="" src="http://thecreativealliance.org/images/site/creative-alliance-logo.jpg" />
    <div id="logout" class="login-reg-link">{module_whosloggedin,/login}</div>
    <h1>Showcase Gallery</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="menu"> {module_menu,550428}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socialtwist.com/2010010232558-1/script.js"></script>
    <a class="st-taf" href="http://tellafriend.socialtwist.com:80" onclick="return false;" style="border:0;padding:0;margin:0;"><img alt="SocialTwist Tell-a-Friend" style="border:0;padding:0;margin:0;" src="http://images.socialtwist.com/2010010232558-1/button.png" onmouseout="STTAFFUNC.hideHoverMap(this)" onmouseover="STTAFFUNC.showHoverMap(this, '2010010232558-1', window.location, document.title)" onclick="STTAFFUNC.cw(this, {id:'2010010232558-1', link: window.location, title: document.title });" /></a>
    <div class="header-search">
      <form name="catsearchform1870" method="post" action="/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=852&ID=/search-results.htm" class="cmxform">
        <fieldset>
          <ol>
            <li>
              <input class="cat_textbox_smallish" type="text" name="CAT_Search" id="CAT_Search" value="Search" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="image" src="/images/go-btn_12.png" class="login-button" value="Search" />
            </li>
          </ol>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cont">{tag_pagecontent}
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr" id="footer"> {module_contentholder,6762}
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="/facebox/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.trilemma.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.truncate-2.3-pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loading_image : 'loading.gif',
        close_image   : 'closelabel.gif'
      })
            $(".email").each(function(){
            var ats, dots, address, i;
            ats = [ ' at ', ' (at) ', ' [at] ' ];
            dots = [ ' dot ', ' (dot) ', ' [dot] ' ];
            address = $(this).html();
            for ( i = 0; i < ats.length; i++ ) {
                address = address.replace(ats[i], '@');
            }
            for ( i = 0; i < dots.length; i++ ) {
                address = address.replace(dots[i], '.');
            }
            $(this).html('<a href="mailto:' + address + '">' + address + '</a>');
        });
  $('.twitswitch').each(function() {
    var $twitswitch = $(this);
    if ($twitswitch.text() == '') {
      $('#twitterlink').hide();
    }
  });
  $('.linkswitch').each(function() {
    var $twitswitch = $(this);
    if ($twitswitch.text() == '') {
      $('#linkedinlink').hide();
    }
  });
  $('.faceswitch').each(function() {
    var $twitswitch = $(this);
    if ($twitswitch.text() == '') {
      $('#facebooklink').hide();
    }
  });
if($(".twitswitch").html() == "" && $(".linkswitch").html() == "" && $(".faceswitch").html() == "") {
      $("#orconnect").hide();
   }
if ( $("#appswitch:contains('Yes')").length ) {
    $("#reviewhold,#fragment-4 ol,#fragment-4 .form-intros").hide();
    $(".cats-chosen").show();
}
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

            $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){

              var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

              if (i != totalSize) {
                  next = i + 2;
                  $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'><span>Next Page &#187;</span></a>");
              }

              if (i != 0) {
                  prev = i;
                  $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'><span>&#171; Prev Page</span></a>");
              }

            });

            $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
                   $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
                   return false;
               });
            $('.tofour').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 4); // switch to fifth tab
    return false;
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    jQuery('.select-cats').trilemma({max:3,disablelabels:true});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if ( $("#logout:contains('Log out')").length ) {
    $("#logout").append(' or <a href="/manage">Edit Showcase</a>');
}
if ( $(".show-form-cont h2:contains('Add your Showcase')").length ) {
    $("#banner h1").html('Showcase Management');
}
if ( $(".show-form-cont h2:contains('Edit your Showcase')").length ) {
    $("#banner h1").html('Showcase Management');
}
});
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
        delay:                     3000, // in milliseconds
        numThumbs:                 20, // The number of thumbnails to show page
        preloadAhead:              40, // Set to -1 to preload all images
        enableTopPager:            false,
        enableBottomPager:         true,
        maxPagesToShow:            7,  // The maximum number of pages to display in either the top or bottom pager
        imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
        controlsContainerSel:      undefined,
        captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
        loadingContainerSel:       '#loader',
        renderSSControls:          true, // Specifies whether the slideshow's Play and Pause links should be rendered
        renderNavControls:         true, // Specifies whether the slideshow's Next and Previous links should be rendered
        playLinkText:              'Play',
        pauseLinkText:             'Pause',
        prevLinkText:              'Previous',
        nextLinkText:              'Next',
        nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
        prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
        enableHistory:             false, // Specifies whether the url's hash and the browser's history cache should update when the current slideshow image changes
        enableKeyboardNavigation:  true, // Specifies whether keyboard navigation is enabled
        autoStart:                 false, // Specifies whether the slideshow should be playing or paused when the page first loads
        syncTransitions:           false, // Specifies whether the out and in transitions occur simultaneously or distinctly
        defaultTransitionDuration: 1000, // If using the default transitions, specifies the duration of the transitions
        onSlideChange:             undefined, // accepts a delegate like such: function(prevIndex, nextIndex) { ... }
        onTransitionOut:           undefined, // accepts a delegate like such: function(slide, caption, isSync, callback) { ... }
        onTransitionIn:            undefined, // accepts a delegate like such: function(slide, caption, isSync) { ... }
        onPageTransitionOut:       undefined, // accepts a delegate like such: function(callback) { ... }
        onPageTransitionIn:        undefined, // accepts a delegate like such: function() { ... }
        onImageAdded:              undefined, // accepts a delegate like such: function(imageData, $li) { ... }
        onImageRemoved:            undefined  // accepts a delegate like such: function(imageData, $li) { ... }
    });
});

</script>
{module_contentholder,8514}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really need to learn to post more narrow and concise questions and narrow the example code down a *lot*.

Comment: Exactly, there is no way we are gonna sit back and debug this for you.

Comment: Thought it may stand out to some. I have heard that .html() can screw things up in jQuery. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all you're javascript is correct. I have a feeling that jQuery is loading fine, but the js stops running after it gets to a certain point.

Example: First line of your posted js, you have a facebox call that doesn't end with a semicolon.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loading_image : 'loading.gif',
        close_image   : 'closelabel.gif'
      })
```

I'd check to make sure there aren't more silly syntax mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am researching jQuery debugging methods now. Any advice on the right approach here? An easy to follow method???

Comment: Unfortunately, ie doesn't really have as good of tools as firefox does (firebug), which lets you step incrementally through the js to see where the errors lie. You could try Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar -  http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en (admittedly, I've never used it).

Comment: Thanks for your time munch. Really appreciate it. Has not fixed the issue but I have decided to not support IE6 on this project. It is not in their budget for me to mess with this so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should have IE Inspector installed on your debug machine to inspect your HTML Tree. There's chance that some HTML was poor formed cause stupid IE6 to behave strangely.
If this does not do a help, then enable Script Debug in your Visual Studio, try insert debugger statement somewhere in your code and start to step over piece of your code.